# R-Caret : Not-meaningful class probabilities and AUC value

Tags: r, probability, roc, caret, auc

I am very new to ML therefore my question might be primitive. I am working on a binary-class problem. The response (target) variable is `occurrence` : a factor variable with two levels : `oui` and `non` (french equivalents of yes and no). The `trainset` has 175 rows (of which 173 rows with `non` and 2 rows with `oui` target values) and looks like :

```
occurrence  QMAX    deve    tm  P15M  P30M  P1H  P4H  P6H  P12H  P24H   P48H
non         35.6    72.0    34.3 5.5 10.2  12.9 17.3  18.4 18.7  18.7   18.7
non        238.9   143.3    49.5 3.9 6.6   11.5 20.7  28.5 42.3  48.9   65.6
non         23.5    72.0    39.3 6.6 8.8   12.0 17.6  17.6 25.4  26.5   28.4
....
oui        2396.5   72.0   34.1  28.5 47.7 68.6 112.1 112.3 125.8 125.9 126.0
```

the `testset` has exactly the same structure but of 19 rows of which 18 rows with `non` and 1 rows with `oui` target values). I use `rf` (random forest) of `caret` package to predict `testset` based on `trainset` :

```
train.control <- trainControl(method = "none",
                              search = "grid",
                              classProbs = TRUE)
expandgrid  <- expand.grid(.mtry = 4)
model.train <- train(occurrence ~ .,
                     data = trainset, 
                     method = "rf", 
                     trControl = train.control,
                     tuneGrid = expandgrid)
predict.class <- predict(model.train, testset)
```

I need to get `classe probabilities` for each row in my `trainset`, so I do :

```
classprobs <- predict(model.train, testset, type = "prob")
```

What I get is as follows :

```
non oui
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
1   0
```

as probability, it gives either 1 or 0 values and **no values in between**. 
So, when I construct `roc` object using `pROC` package :

```
ROC <- roc(testset$occurrence, classprobs$oui, levels = c("oui", "non"), auc = TRUE) 
thresh <- coords(ROC, x = "best", best.method = "closest.topleft", ret = "threshold", transpose = FALSE)
```

the returned AUC value and best threshold are :

```
ROC$auc
Area under the curve: 0.5

thresh
[1] -Inf  Inf
```

When I use other data sets such as `iris` (after subsetting it to a data.frame with binary `versicolor` and `virginica` response variables) and use the same script, reported probabilities values are not exclusively 0 and 1, i.e. there are probability values such as 0.04, 0.96 and the corresponding `roc` has a `non-Inf` `best.threshold` value.

I would be thankful if you could help me find what is wrong with my case.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58476103/333599 see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/147320

Comment: ok, thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very imbalanced dataset. As you have stated:

> The trainset has 175 rows (of which 173 rows with non and 2 rows with
>   oui target values)

When you run any ML model in caret, by default it is trained to improve accuracy, which means getting the labels correct in your training set. When most of your data set is "non", the model simply needs to assign everything to "non" and its accuracy will be 173/175.

When this happens, the AUC etc simply doesn't make sense anymore, because the other label is missing.

You need to have more of the other label before you go on...